# Query without listagg function

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

Can someone help me to get desired output without using listagg function.

Requirement: 
Write a query to get the job_id and related employee's id.

```
Output:
    jobname     Empno
    AC_ACCOUNT  206
    AC_MGR      205
    AD_ASST     200
    AD_PRES     100
    AD_VP       101,102
    FI_ACCOUNT  110 ,113 ,111 ,109 ,112
```

I have achieved using listagg function.

```
  select  jobname, listagg(empno, ',') within group (order by empno) empno
  from emp group by jobname;
```

But I want to know if possible to write a query without using listagg fucntion?

Comment: Yes i guess you achive so using recursive queries...

Comment: Anwaar, If possible can you please provide recursive query?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use hierarchical query.

```
with sel as (
select job_id, employee_id
from employees
order by job_id, employee_id)
, sel2 as (
select rownum r, job_id, employee_id
from sel)
, sel3 as (
select sel2.*, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path (employee_id,','),',') res, level l
from sel2
connect by prior job_id=job_id and  r=prior r+1
order by job_id)

select job_id, res
from sel3 s
where l = (select max(l) from sel3 where job_id=s.job_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you want to use PLSQL to achieve that. LISTAGG was created for that very reason, to achieve that output. Let oracle do the heavy stuff for you

Comment: Not agree with you. There are some solutions - hierarchical query, XMLAGG, and maybe recursive queries

Comment: yeah you just proved it. Nice answer

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Which one is best way to use while checking performance wise (hierarchical query, XMLAGG, recursive queries, Listagg)

Comment: @BalakumarSubramanian Listagg of course. Because you don't need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

Check out XMLAGG function. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm)

Comment: PK20, Am not aware of XMLAGG function, could you please provide some sample query to get desired output.

Comment: @BalakumarSubramanian Did you check the link provided? Did you try something? Let me know what you tried and what results you got. I would be able to help you from there.

Comment: SELECT XMLELEMENT("Department",
   XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("Employee", 
   deptno||' '||empno)
   ORDER BY empno))
   as "Dept_list"     
   FROM emp
output: <Department><Employee>20 7369</Employee><Employee>30 7499</Employee><Employee>30 7521</Employee><Employee>20 7566</Employee><Employee>30 7654</Employee><Employee>30 7698</Employee><Employee>10 7782</Employee><Employee>20 7788</Employee><Employee>10 7839</Employee><Employee>30 7844</Employee><Employee>20 7876</Employee><Employee>30 7900</Employee><Employee>20 7902</Employee><Employee>10 7934</Employee></Department> . How can I use it?